# find strings in cell array using wildcards

Tags: matlab, find, cell

I have a cell array of which the last part looks like this:

```
Columns 8372 through 8375

    {'w20091231_2000.nc'}    {'w20091231_2020.nc'}    {'w20091231_2040.nc'}    {'w20091231_2100.nc'}

  Columns 8376 through 8379

    {'w20091231_2120.nc'}    {'w20091231_2140.nc'}    {'w20091231_2200.nc'}    {'w20091231_2220.nc'}

  Columns 8380 through 8383

    {'w20091231_2240.nc'}    {'w20091231_2300.nc'}    {'w20091231_2320.nc'}    {'w20091231_2340.nc'}

  Columns 8384 through 8387

    {'wD1.nc'}    {'wD2.nc'}    {'wD3.nc'}    {'wD4.nc'}
```

Now I want to rearrange this array so that it only contains the last four strings.`{'wD1.nc'}    {'wD2.nc'}    {'wD3.nc'}    {'wD4.nc'}`

I tried

```
IndexC = strfind(names,'wD*.nc');
Index = find(not(cellfun('isempty',IndexC)))
```

and

```
Index = find(contains(names,'wD*.nc'));
names2=names(Index)
```

both work if wD*.nc is wD4.nc but then of course I only select the one value and not the four that I want.
How do I get to use the `*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do some googling but found this https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77039-comparing-strings-with-wildcards , and something like the following seems to work:

```
IndexC = regexp(names, regexptranslate('wildcard', 'wD*.nc'));
Index = find(not(cellfun('isempty',IndexC)));
names2=names(Index)
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line using regexp with the `match` option:

```
x = regexp([x{:}],'wD\d+\.nc','match')
```

Comment: Although using `[x{:}]` *could* give undesired results if there happened to be a match across consecutive elements of `x`. You could avoid this by replacing `[x{:}]` with something like `strjoin(x,'#')` to concatenate them with some non-matching character in between.